# pool pump wiring size

Tags: electrical

The pump is 115v 9 amp draw. The run length from breaker box to outlet is between 70 and 75'. I have a coil of 14/2 left over from my barn wiring project. I've done some online checking and think I am ok with this setup but you can never have too much info. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is this a cord-and-plug connected pool pump, or a hardwired one? Is the pool a storable type or a permanent pool, and if it's storable, what size is it?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to disagree with Harper on this but I would always run a minimum of 12-gauage wire for a 9-Amp pool pump with a circuit run of 75-feet.  The pool pump is going to be considered a continuous load. This will require a buffer factor of at least 25%. A continuous load at 75' would require another deration factor. A pool pump is not an incidental load.  14-guage wire is designed to carry minimal loads.  And a pool pump/motor is an expensive item.  We shouldn't take a chance on taxing that motor with inadequate wiring.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use interior wire (NM aka Romex) for outdoor, underground or outside conduit applications.  As an example if the cable contains that paper wadding, that's a big no-go.  You need UF cable if direct burying, or that or THWN-2/XHHW individual wires for conduit.

#14 NM is generally white (rarely black). UF is gray.

Voltage drop wise, that sounds fine.  You don't even need to think about voltage drop til at least 60' on a 120V circuit, and even then only if you are running at hard circuit limits (which you should not) and believe in 3% (which you should not).

Given that you are well under 15A, and 3% isn't that important for a panel-final load run, you are fine.